# OpenShift + Diet.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

Trying to get a simple [Diet.js](http://dietjs.com/) server running on OpenShift (free plan) but the server never starts (runs fine locally). The domain itself (http://twilio-levelout.rhcloud.com/) returns a 503 and the logs throw:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
```

Here's the code:

```
var server = require('diet'),
app = server();

var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function ($) {
    $.end('Hello World!');
});

app.listen("http://" + server_ip_address + ":" + server_port);
```

The server runs with the default example and a simple Express app but not the above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access error usually means that you are not using the proper port or are trying to bind to interface you have no access to, but when I tried your example, It did not even work on my local machine.

The problem in your example is that app.listen should appear before app.get.

Your example should look like this:

```js
var server = require('diet'),
app = server();

var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

app.listen('http://' + server_ip_address + ':' + server_port);

app.get('/', function ($) {
      $.end('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @MartinB - I originally had app.listen first but changed it when attempting to fix, must have left it when pasting code to question. Don't think it makes a difference. It should run locally - what error did you get? As for the address/port - this must be correct as the same env vars work for my Express app.

Comment: `➭ Diet  (0.9.3) ☺
 http://dietjs.com/

/home/anonymous/gittest/node_modules/diet/models/router.js:66
   if(!app.routes[method][pathRegister]) app.routes[method][pathRegister] = []
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '/' of undefined
    at App.get (/home/anonymous/gittest/node_modules/diet/models/router.js:66:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anonymous/gittest/server.js:7:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    ...`

Comment: ah yes! listen should be first then. still doesn't get round the OpenShift error : ( any more ideas?

Comment: When you add `console.log(app.location)` below `app.listen()`, you will find out that the app is trying to use an interface it doesn't have access to. If I look on my local machine it just binds to all the available interfaces. As far as I can tell this appears to be a diet.js bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MartinB - I've raised an issue on the Diet repo https://github.com/adamhalasz/diet/issues/9